# Using Redemption, How can I add a default Signature to an outgoing Email Message?

Tags: outlook-redemption

Here is the code that I am using. I have spent some time looking at the Redemption objects, but, nothing jumps out at me:

```
    public static bool PopEmail(string domainUserName, string mSubject, string mBody, string mTo, string mCc = "", string mBcc = "", List<String> fileAttachments = null)
    {
        log.Info("Starting to Pop Outlook Email Message");
        RDOSession oSession = new RDOSession();
        try
        {
            oSession.LogonExchangeMailbox(domainUserName, string.Empty);
            if (oSession.LoggedOn)
            {
                RDOMail oMail = oSession.GetDefaultFolder(rdoDefaultFolders.olFolderOutbox).Items.Add("IPM.Note");
                oMail.Subject = mSubject;
                oMail.Body = mBody;
                oMail.To = mTo;
                oMail.CC = mCc;
                oMail.BCC = mBcc;
                if (fileAttachments != null)
                {
                    foreach (string file in fileAttachments)
                    {
                        object newFile = file;
                        oMail.Attachments.Add(newFile, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                        newFile = null;
                    }
                }
                oMail.Display();
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oMail);
                oMail = null;
            }
            oSession.Logoff();
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oSession);
            oSession = null;
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            log.Info("Outlook Email has been Popped.");
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            log.Error("Outlook Pop Email Failed.");
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added code to append to the oMail.HTMLBody which reads the signature from the C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures folder. This file is generated via a plug in written by one of our developers that reads information from Exchange to determine User Name, Title, Phone, Fax, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The signature is actually inserted by the Outlook inspector object on instantiation, so if your code is running inside an Outlook addin you could probably try saving the item and then reopening it from the OOM as a `_MailItem` via `_Namespace.GetItemFromId` and then calling its `GetInspector` method (you don't actually have to do anything with the returned inspector reference).

Note that I haven't tried this with an item initially created via RDO. I usually create the items in OOM and then create an RDO wrapper.

If your code is running outside of Outlook you'd have to use OLE to get a reference to its `_Application` object and then pull the `_Namespace` object from there. If you are using standalone MAPI without Outlook installed the signature functionality is completely unavailable.

Comment: I have added code to append to the oMail.HTMLBody which reads the signature from the C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures folder. This file is generated via a plug in written by one of our developers that reads information from Exchange to determine User Name, Title, Phone, Fax, etc. Thank you for your answer.